# PHP two file patterns match same file

Tags: php, filepath

I have multiple file patterns (used by `fnmatch`), but it may occur that multiple file patterns match the same file. How can I avoid it with validation of the patterns? For example the file is example.csv, and patterns are `*.csv`, `example.csv`, `ex*.csv`, `ex*le.csv`, `example*`.

Comment: What are you doing with the files that match? Is your concern that a file will be used twice? Then just keep your file names in an array and check the array for the file name before you add it there.

Comment: There's no way to find out whether a files matches two patterns until the file exist. If you refer to current files, you'll have to run all patterns and compare results.

Comment: these files will be processed, and want it to match with an exact pattern, but dont want race conditions

Comment: the patterns are created before files copied to that folder